# multiple select not deselecting when clicked on

Tags: jquery, select

I have a multiple select element, and first element has a class `sel-all` and other
has `sel-child`

```
<select multiple="multiple">
    <option class="sel-all">All</option>
    <option class="sel-child">UsernameOne</option>
    <option class="sel-child">UsernameTwo</option>
    <option class="sel-child">UsernameThree</option>
    <option class="sel-child">UsernameFour</option>
</select>
```

What i want to achieve,

when i click on `sel-all` element, all elements should be selected and value should be change to `Deselect All`
and `sel-all` class will be remove and `sel-del` will be added.

when clicked on `sel-all` element, then all element options are unselected and itself.

And now.. delselecting is not working..

http://jsfiddle.net/ucBtL/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use delegation here so when an element is dynamically added, handler delegated still works. BTW, element selector is filtered as delegate level, so your logic of toggling classes is respected:

{refactorized your code and use .prop() instead of .attr() for property selected}

http://jsfiddle.net/ucBtL/3/

```
$('select').on('click','.sel-all',function(){
console.log("element is clicked");

    // select all sel-child element
    $(".sel-child").prop('selected', 'selected');
    // remove current selection on sel-all
    $(this).prop('selected', false).text('Deselect All').toggleClass("sel-del sel-all");    

});

$('select').on('click','.sel-del',function(){
console.log("element is clicked");

     // unselect all sel-child element
     $(".sel-child").prop('selected', false);
    // remove current selection on sel-all
     $(this).prop('selected', false).text('All').toggleClass("sel-all sel-del");    

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Event handlers are attached to the elements that exists at the time the handler is bound, changing an elements class later on does not attach the event handler to that element. Instead of delegating events to a parent, you can use the click function that is already attached to the element, and toggle between the two states :

```
$(".sel-all").on('click', function(){
    $(this).prop('selected', false)
           .toggleClass("sel-del sel-all") // you can remove this, not needed
           .text(function() {
                return $(this).text() == 'All' ? 'Deselect All' : 'All';
            }).siblings().prop('selected', $(this).text() != 'All');
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ucBtL/5/)